# How to point cities in a SVG map?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I pointing cities in a svg map like this: http://incassobond.nl/arnhem-incassoburau-inschakelen-no-cure-no-pay.htm
Below is my code which is a map of the Netherlands

```js
.lw { font-size: 60px; }
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        svg { height: 50vw; }
        path{ fill: #d3d3d3; transition: .6s fill; }
        path:hover { fill: #eee }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Naamloos document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="svg3805" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="204.22mm" width="172.94mm" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 612.78192 723.61818">
        <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-56.466 -190.55)" stroke="#fff" stroke-width=".5" fill="#ccc">
            <path id="NL-DR" d="m524.64 314.38 4.33 1.6 2.01-5.29 1.17-0.36 0.37-3.37 2.69-8.21 3.38-3.69 0.49-2.55 5.03-2.74 1.4-1.34 0.09-0.93 5.35-1.39 2.75-0.32 5.4 1.93 1 2.58 0.6 0.02 2.34 4.09 1.14 3.18 2.39-0.81 1.18 4.1h1.32l3.54 3.11 1.06 2.92 1.74 2.13 0.04 1.81 9.25-3.71 6.57 0.35 1.25 0.84 29.78 31.93 12.71 18.61 1.53 1.33 3.34 0.89-4.49 10.91 3.76 0.4 0.49 1.85 0.59-0.05 2.34 3.43 1.03 1.04 1.25-0.13-0.54 2.72 3.18-0.16-3.31 7.5-2.65 43.5-2.2 2.6-4.7-1.17-1.22-1.17-1.92 0.13-2.7-1.38-3.39 2.08-2.67 0.26-2.95-0.88-0.45-1.59-2.93-1.01-2.5 0.26-1.13-0.94-1.69 1.04-1.8 0.18-2.35-0.88-2.27 1.14-5.89-1.3-2.09 0.73-0.52 0.83-1.44-0.52-2.6 0.78-4.87 5.05-1.82-0.11 1.52-5.74-15.03-6.46-10.1 2.27-6.03 4.63 0.94 9.78-2.22-2.08-4.49-0.32-1.51-1.69-1.12 2.47-2.67 0.37-1.48-1.28-0.55-2.02-1.96 2.47-1.43-0.73-0.5 0.91-1.51-0.05-1.82 1.43-1.34-1.56-0.4-2.71-1.78-3.82-5.84-4.22 0.38-1.69-0.54-0.93-4.12 1.06-1.1 0.91-1.43-1.58-1.71 0.88-1.34-1.25-1.13-0.08-1.77-2.11-2.69-0.72-1.59-1.49-2.11 0.5-0.85 1.17-2.41-0.68-1.22 0.5-3-3.57-5.8-14.96 1.06-1.49 6.71-2.42 0.19-1.26 5.16-5.71-10.77-12.33-2.35-3.63 13.31-9.42 4.21-5.86 3.89-3.74 7.5 0.55 4.97 5.1 9.37-6.7 5.52-10.45-10.35-16.08 0.69-8.93-9.44-3.57z" title="Drenthe" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-FL" d="m383.88 462.08-0.68-0.75 2.77-7.32 3.85-2.49 0.3-1.12-1.82-5.61-8.78-14.14 0.36-0.26 8.85 14.14 1.87 6.05-0.4 1.27-3.91 2.44-2.1 5.11-0.31 2.68zm45.04-80.51 1.58 0.31 1.25 1.23 1.08-0.44-0.98-2.95 3.17 0.97 5.73 5.8 0.98 3.79 0.59-0.34 3.58 4.88h2.9l3.59 1.25 10.22 8.35 3.29 9.31 1.11 0.57 2.06 3.75-0.38 1.59-2.88 2.16-1.79 2.03 0.06 0.89 5.81 1.59 2.52 2.21 2.58 0.7 2.28 2.52-0.79 1.35-3.56 2.37-5.24 1.14-3.88 2.63-2.34 0.29-2.06-1.35-9.32 2.05-1.25 1.04-9.38-0.03-0.06 6.86 5.19 0.21 6.74 7.19 1.74 8.62-3.47 12-1.85 0.16-2.21 4.22 0.85 1.61-2.07 3.55-3.08 3.03-7.85 6.37-1.35-0.49 0.17 0.85-2.33 2.12-3.07 1.99-2.96 0.41-4.32 3.7-1.33-0.98-5 2.74-1.27-0.98-2.69 0.88-1.85 2.87-6.88 19.91-19.92 5.93-11.11-10.58-3.81-3.77-4.65-3.07-9.73-2.45-11 1.88-2.23-2.07 1.03-1.68-2.12-1.4 0.66-1.24-0.27-5.01-1.63-3.1 0.03-1.53 5.41-3.26 0.81-1.86 7.18-4.24 2.59-0.44 1.46-2.04 23.64-16.37 2.58-0.8 6.12-5.5 0.3-0.99-0.6-2.1-0.98 0.21 0.14-1.38 0.74 0.23 1.66-1.3 2.44-4.62 5.48-0.57 5.36-5.12-0.48-0.96 0.55-0.55 0.52 0.86 4.48-4.6 10.59-3.07 3.51-2.89-5-8.06-2.83-2.08 0.52-0.44-0.74-0.96-1 0.18 0.27-26.71 10.57-17.2 7.88-1.78z" title="Flevoland" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-FR" d="m374.77 318.92 2.55 1.68 1.38 3.55-3.05-0.21-1.38-2.44-0.35-2.34 0.85-0.24zm-5.56 0.16 0.06 1.1-5.74 1.26-12.99 11.45-0.08 0.68-1.66 0.79 1.41-0.03-1.58 0.21-5.62 4.88-0.65-0.87 5.51-4.83-0.09-0.58 0.73-0.39-0.49 0.84 14.79-13.05 4.78-1.66 1.62 0.2zm-41.49-61.5 4.19 0.79 0.41 1.32-1.22 1.14-0.71-0.32 0.3 0.55-1.91-0.32-2.36 0.66-3.17 2.59-11.3 4.67 0.74 3.11-1.47 0.87 0.05 2.56-3.86 1.58-2.15 2.32-4.45 0.53-2.9 1.58-1.31-0.37-0.76-2.24 8.96-5.67 7.12-7.1 9.3-6.34 6.5-1.91zm11.13 4.6-2.01 1.93-1.96-0.05 0.92-0.98-1.09-0.95 4.04-4.12 1.49-0.4 0.36 1.74-1.75 2.83zm166.05-31.73-3.69 5.38 0.93 5.74 1.68 1.8 5.9 1.8 1.72 3.41 2.96-1.43 5.52 1.9-0.84 7.32 1.96 1.22-2.31 1.58-1.23 3.38-1.47-0.19-1.17 0.69 0.17 5.52-0.82 0.4-0.71-0.5-1.28 2.74-0.96 0.37 0.46 0.66-0.81 0.98 0.16 2.03-2.74 0.45 2.67 4.88-0.21 1.18-1.49 2.79-1.6 1.74-1.42 0.42-0.22 1.4-3.32 5.58-0.7 9.42 4.83 5.29 5.21 0.79 4.37-0.18 2.31 1.24 2.09 2.6 3.8 1.52-1.28 3.52 9.43 3.57-0.68 8.93 10.35 16.08-5.52 10.45-9.37 6.7-4.97-5.1-7.5-0.55-3.89 3.74-4.21 5.86-13.31 9.41-6.11 4.02-2.77-0.1-1.79 0.73 0.21 3.19-3.73 2.01-0.71-1.44-4.13 1.12-2.09-0.99-2.15-5.38-2.83 0.94-0.02 1.38-1.47-0.6-2.41 0.52-0.71 0.86 0.02 2.04-4.21 3.97-3.31 1.57-5.87-1.57-1 0.57-0.35-1.07-2.17-1.49-3.78 2.64-0.59 0.34-0.98-3.79-5.73-5.8-3.17-0.97 0.98 2.95-1.08 0.44-1.25-1.23-1.58-0.31 0.11-1.12-1.46 0.57-0.7-1.49-3.99-0.21 0.11-0.99-0.92 1.7-1.68-0.29-0.73-0.84 0.3-2.09-1.77-1.31-4.23 2.46-2.21-0.31-2.83 0.65-1.06 2.77-4.15 1.57-14.86-5.7-5.43 1.65-4.35-2.2-4.46-4.1-2.5-3.64 2.79-3.4 4.53-2.12 0.87-1.23 0.16-2.67-0.84-4.14-0.87-1.05 1.79-0.86-0.6-0.42 1.08 0.03 0.43-1.96-0.55-1.39-0.76 0.03 1.17-0.29 0.16-1.21-1.72-5.4-0.57-4.43 1.38-2.33 0.05-2.7-1.39-0.39-0.25-1.44 0.73-0.29 0.11-1.1 0.43 0.31-0.21-3.94-0.55 3.81-0.6 0.42-1.09-2.52-1.55-1.71-0.25-1.55 1.22-0.21 0.82 0.71v-0.68l0.67-0.05 0.49 0.79 0.73-0.1-1.77-3.44-0.3-3.13-1.71-3.26-5.93 4.89-0.92-1.52 2.07-0.74 4.42-4.28 0.51-3.44 2.56-1.55 1.35-1.76 1.83-11.34-0.05-1.11-1.06-1.05 1.9-1.76 2.6-7.96 1.61-2.58 5.49-5.64 7.14-4.46 4.42-4.54 0.96-2.69 4.4-4.44 4.46-2.3 11.87-3.73 11.6-7.03 16.19-7.46 3.31-1.91-1.6-2.7 0.44 0.61 0.35-0.37 0.98 2.28 4.56-0.03 8.61-2.97 0.43 0.45 2.36-0.42 4.21-1.35 8.36-1.09 2.55 0.69 0.28-0.69 0.32 0.69 0.67-1.03 6.95 1.46 6.28-2.97 1.06-0.08 1.22 1.07zm-105.26-9.44-2.01 0.48 5.13-0.19-0.11 2.54-3.18 1.62-2.07-0.13-4.62 2.86-2.31-0.98 0.29 2.25-3.67-1.46 2.03 1.93 2.45 0.93-1.2 0.16-0.49 0.95-10.11 0.26-2.47 0.64-6.12 4.87-3.29 1.51-1.87-0.69-0.38 0.74-1.85 0.49-0.6 1.27-5.85-0.58-2.47 2.17-0.74-0.56-2.61 0.32-0.66 0.9 0.09 1.9-1.8-0.4-3.45 3.31-1.87-0.45-2.66-1.93-0.44-3.28 3.4-3.33 2.18-3.89 0.28 0.77 0.66-2.22 19.88-3.89 1.25 0.27 15.4-5.01 13.39-5.46 3.12-0.58 2.71 0.53-0.33 0.95-3.03 0.41zm84.71-3.36 0.27 2.12-0.4-0.69-2.17 1.86-0.87-0.42-0.33-1.48 0.92-1.35 2.58-0.04zm-53.55-0.06 19.15-1.56 19.37 0.05 1.74 0.85-0.9 0.95-1.6 0.34-8.45-0.21-2.96 1.64-13.34 3.66-4.64-0.03-0.41 1.27-0.02-1.7-7.67-0.82-3.31 3.31-5.71 1.54-0.49 1.25-5.44-2.83-2.59-3.6 0.63-4.93 2.39-2.09 10.44 2.63 3.81 0.28zm67.63-13.05 1.42 0.27 1.55 1.46 4.51 0.48 18.02-2.2 5.78-0.24 0.29 0.45-2.77 1.96-8.67 3-1.06 1.33-3.96 1.86-7.82 1.14 0.74 1.25-1.12-1.11h-4.23l-0.32 1.06-0.16-1.01-1.08 0.21-0.71 0.88 0.41 0.56-1.77 0.16 0.57 2.02-3.21-0.27-1.65 1.59-0.68-0.48 0.66-3.34 1.66-4.03 1.42-2.07 3.88-3.08-6.19-1.75-1.17 2.97-1.03-0.16 0.11-0.96 1.09-2.52 5.49 0.57z" title="Friesland" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-GE" d="m453.03 464.1 2.15-0.8 2.46 2.18 3.21 4.51 2.15 5.11 1.2-0.55 0.62 0.57 2.94-1.73 1.37 1.97 6.89-7.13 1.71-0.6 1.11-1.32 4.64 3.01 1.82 3.68 3.65 2.1 1.35 1.63 0.46 6.53 4.21 5.2 0.99 3.55-1.97 7.96-3.31 1.58-3.14 0.6-0.63 0.87 0.26 1.53 2.34 1.55-2.87 1.89-0.01 5.14-0.91 3.12 1.57 0.21 0.63 4 2.71 0.36 0.33 0.6 1.27 2.6 0.13 2.5 2.84 4.6-0.91 2.32 2.69 1.05 1.96-0.18-0.19 1.42-1.44 1.57 0.43 1.65 2.42 1.11 0.72 1.88 0.32-0.77-0.87-1.52 0.62 0.26 0.16-1.16 0.72 0.77 0.59-2.53 4.13 0.03 2.31 1.73 5.05 1.05 3.62 0.26 0.08-0.75 1.04 0.36 2.2-1 1.21 1.39 3.27 0.03 2.66-0.42 0.09-2.19 2-1.49 4.75-0.93 5.52 0.62-0.05 1.29 1.76 3.43 3.19 3.34 1.3 2.63 2.3 0.72 0.94 3.38 2.58 1.95 3.56-0.9 6.29 1.03 5.8-1.42 2.52 2.22-0.4 1.47 1.33 1.23 2.65-2.37 1.61 1.34 0.78-1.36 0.66 0.05 3.26 1.72 0.73 1.26-0.54 1.37 0.41 4.01-1.68 2.7 8.49 2.98 7.13-0.05-0.68 5.32-0.55 0.87-0.54-0.51-0.92 0.87 0.92 2.11-1.96 2.44-6.73 1.13 0.26 1.44-1.6 3.31 0.22 3.28h4.32l6.15 2.95 2.06 2.42 6.46 4.84 0.3 1.28 2.86 0.44 0.57 6.59-0.46 0.81-2.1 0.08-2.44 1.33-0.41 5.46-3.81 5.17-2.9 1.2-0.35 1.23-2.34 0.82-0.76 1.4-1.49 0.72-2.62-2.07-1.89-2.87-2.32-0.25-6.3 2.99-1.01 1.05-1.35-0.23-7.32 2.45-3.07 2.43-1.16-0.92-1.2 0.49-6.03 4.06-1.16 2.13-4.57 1.66-3.15-3.05-2.8 1.67-0.79-1.84-5.54-2.15-0.73 2.91 3.68 2.66-1.21 1.69 0.7 2.45-0.68 0.02 0.52 1.77-0.65 0.58-2.66-1.76-3.46-0.53-0.38-2.2-1.14-1.02-7.64-0.34-1.03-4.67-3.04-1.46-1.2-0.18-2.66 1.59-6.92-0.11-4.17-3.42-0.11-1.02 1.21-0.23-0.34-1-3.39-2.58-0.21 0.48-1.88-1.18-3.61 0.62-1.07 0.82-1.17-0.92-2.12 2.43 2.45 0.05 2.78 1.71 0.97 3.84 3.08 2.48 0.29 5.05-5.76-1.73-4.76-0.36-5.59-3.99-0.87 1.61-1.03 0.44 0.22 1.4-3.21 2.28-0.52-0.54-1.87 0.69-0.81 1.61-1.86 0.94-2.3 0.26-4-1.48-2.56 3.17 2.1 1.63-0.51 0.66-1.26-0.3-0.19 0.84 2.69 1.45 2.21 2.3-0.74 2.27 0.51 1.05 2.35 0.56-1.04 1.05-0.17 1.35 1.09 1.25-0.08 0.74-5.37 3.75-0.34 1.7-2.93 0.79-1.35-1.73-1.8-0.56-0.52-2.86-2.99-3.82-4.28 0.25 0.8 3.73-0.89 0.94-2.37-0.43-10.97 1.78-3.4-0.25-2.23-1.43-2.28-3.44-3.75-0.92-3.09-3.83-2.96-0.51-1.69-1.07-3.07-5.54-2.79-0.18-5.56-2.58-4.72 0.59-1.88 2.55-1.02 0.31-3.29-0.82-2.43-2.42-1.57-0.51-1.54 0.66-1.48 3.52-2.85 1.1-3.23-0.05-1.58-0.66-1.96-2.4-1.3 0.02-5.9 8.91-1.74 7.68-8.98 5.07-4.62-0.87-3.35 1.74-4.84-2.5-3.72 0.81-5.19-0.68-5.59 1.42-0.06-1.86 2.53-2.57-1.03-1.3 0.43-3.11-3.61-1.76-2.39-2.07-1.88 0.25-1.54 1.64-1.69-0.08-3.23-4.64-4.24-1.94-3-3.81 2.37 0.05 1.03-4.98-3.4-0.46-0.95-1.58 0.34-1.41-0.58-1.86 0.41-0.43 1.8 1.58 4.01-0.1 1.53 0.61 2.9-1.86-1.09-0.67-0.15-1.74 4.32-1.28 1.67-3.17 3.67 0.44 0.65-2.87 2.19-4.06 0.75 0.35-0.1-1.61 6.93-12.39 2.17 1.41 2.88 0.23 3.2-4.53 1.2-0.31 4.86 3.61 4.57 0.87 2.45 1.64 1.35 0.08 1.93-0.98 2.82-2.89 5.15 0.18 4.97-1.9 3.12-2.33 4.32 0.85 3.7-0.08 3.2 2.26 5.11 1.89 2.28 2.72 5.33 1.58 2.68 1.8 1.59-1.41 0.91 0.51-0.07-1.31 0.94-0.23-0.71-3.89 0.58-1.72-1.6-1.89-1.03-3.16-2.26-1.38-1.06-2.77-2.42-1.82 0.87-0.02 0.21-4.49-3.01-1.13 0.21-1.77-1.21-0.52 1.24-7.54-0.26-2.01-0.96-0.64-0.13-1.85-0.6-0.41 0.03-2.19-1.33 0.72-0.41-0.48-1.41 0.36 1.33 3.44-0.11 0.51-1.28-0.38-0.51 0.9 1.05 0.43-1.52 1.62-2.72-0.18-0.41 1.39-3.2 0.49-3.75-2.6 1.71-2.18 2.28-1.44-0.21-2.67 1.46-1.83-1.11-0.72 3.27 0.34-0.63-1.6-1.5-1.15 0.58-1.37 1.73-0.25 0.77-1.49-2.13-1.06 0.19-1.88-2.91-0.61 0.22-1.73-1.46-1.52-8.56-1.72-0.65-2.99 2.52-0.72 0.36-3.5-6.47-5.28 1.82-7.83 19.92-5.93 6.89-19.91 1.85-2.87 2.69-0.88 1.26 0.99 5-2.74 1.33 0.98 4.32-3.7 2.96-0.41 3.07-1.99 2.33-2.12-0.18-0.86 1.35 0.49 7.85-6.36 3.08-3.03 2.08-3.55-0.86-1.61 2.22-4.22 1.85-0.15z" title="Gelderland" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-GR" d="m599.67 218.2 1.39 0.34 2.55-2.07 2.75 1.11 0.33 0.93-0.4 1.3-2.75-0.56-0.11 0.5 2.47 0.61-0.17 0.72-1.44 0.19 4.35 0.69 0.11-0.53-1.54-0.53 0.67-2.54 3.1 0.98 3.5 3.34-1.33 4.77-0.17 3.71 2.29 3.31-0.43 0.69 0.78 0.71-0.21 2.78 1.74 7.91 5.67 4.1-0.93 1.85 10.13 3.81 2.22 1.66 6.06 1.69 4.68-0.11 0.66-0.95 2.82-1 0.03 0.69-2.33 2.14-0.05 4.23-1.27 3.51 1.19 2.56 2.45 1.66 5.47 0.4 1.61 1.19 1.87 0.5 1.09-0.42 1.47 1.11 5.41 1.66 0.55-2.03 1.34 11.63-1.49 2.61 2.96 2.74-3.78 1.16-2.15 4.69-0.06 2.53-1.55 2.21 0.63 4.39 2.85 2.1-0.33 8.75 2.06 17.36 0.81 2.07-1.28 1.6-4.16 15.26-12.14 20.13-2.63 3.37-0.35 0.76 0.79 2.95-3.18 0.16 0.54-2.72-1.25 0.13-1.03-1.05-2.34-3.42-0.59 0.05-0.49-1.86-3.77-0.39 4.49-10.91-3.34-0.89-1.54-1.33-12.71-18.6-29.78-31.94-1.25-0.84-6.57-0.34-9.26 3.71-0.03-1.81-1.74-2.13-1.06-2.92-3.54-3.1h-1.31l-1.19-4.11-2.39 0.82-1.14-3.19-2.34-4.08-0.6-0.03-1-2.58-5.4-1.92-2.75 0.32-5.35 1.4-0.09 0.92-1.39 1.34-5.03 2.74-0.49 2.55-3.39 3.69-2.69 8.21-0.36 3.37-1.17 0.37-2.01 5.28-4.34-1.6-3.8-1.52-2.09-2.6-2.31-1.24-4.37 0.18-5.21-0.79-4.83-5.29 0.7-9.42 3.32-5.58 0.22-1.4 1.42-0.42 1.6-1.74 1.49-2.79 0.22-1.19-2.67-4.88 2.74-0.45-0.16-2.03 0.81-0.98-0.46-0.66 0.96-0.37 1.28-2.74 0.71 0.5 0.82-0.4-0.17-5.52 1.17-0.69 1.47 0.19 1.23-3.38 2.31-1.58-1.96-1.22 0.84-7.32-5.52-1.9-2.96 1.43-1.72-3.41-5.9-1.8-1.68-1.8-0.93-5.74 3.69-5.38 1.39-0.4 0.05 1.01 0.63 0.03 7.55-1.88 6.52 3.31 2.36 2.52 4.1-3.04 9.29-3.92 26.32-3.36 21.9-8.03 8.85-0.88 5.85 2.35zm-60.67-16.76 0.74 0.13-0.08 0.66-4.07-0.61 1.17-0.53 2.24 0.35zm28.25-1.54 1.11 0.19-0.66 1.25-2.55-1.35 1.2-0.56 0.9 0.47zm4.7-4.52-0.11 0.53-2.23-0.29 0.79 1.94-3.24-1.54-2.56 0.24-0.38-0.5 1-1.54 1.01-0.29 3.42 0.37 2.3 1.08zm-19.48-0.64 2.56 0.58 2.67 2.63-3.21-0.48-1.01-0.98-0.33 2.07-2.36-0.26-0.85 0.58 0.49 1.27-0.78 0.53-1.39-0.4-0.71-0.58-0.35-2.1-2.52-2.31 0.78-4.46 0.6 0.08 0.68 2.31 5.73 1.52z" title="Groningen" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-LI" d="m453.35 660.12 0.89-0.94-0.8-3.73 4.28-0.25 2.99 3.82 0.52 2.86 1.8 0.56 1.35 1.73 2.93-0.79 0.28 1.43 6.03 0.15 5.16 2.76 1.42 2.14 1.43 0.51-0.21 1.14h-1.61l-0.98 1.22 1.01 3.21-0.71 1.81 0.65 3.54 7.37 3.36 0.95-0.33 0.36 0.71 4.64 0.81-1.79 6.21-1.2 2.87-0.6-0.28-0.43 4.02 4.75 3.71 0.99 1.9 4.28 4.14 3.73 7.42 3.39 2.66 2.26 3.96-0.03 5.29 1.61 4.95-0.69 6.35-0.83 0.36-0.06 4.58-1.19 6.96 3.14-0.15-1.87 3.49 1.87 6.45-5.62 5.18 0.39 1.49-3.83 0.83-2.29 6.24-3.94 5.45-1 2.93-6.01 6.63-2.1 1.29 2.24 4.78-2.85 1.04 1 9.22 1.41 2.74 2.69 0.4 3.61-2.82 6.77-3.27 2.63 2.04-6.7 3.32 5.57 3.8-1.94 1.34-0.08 1.05-5.41 0.81-3.39 2.21-2.41 0.43-0.88 2.69-0.82-0.48-1.22 1.81-2.47 1.03-0.21 1.28-1.96 2.27-1.83 1.4-1.76 0.53-0.7-0.43-0.95 0.71-2.5 2.39-0.95 1.9-1.47 0.53 0.26 0.81-1.71 2.08-0.32 4.07-1.77 0.82 0.3 1.41-3.53 0.15-3.66-7.83-3.52 3.26-4.18 0.58 0.28 1.56 1.89 2.31-0.89 1.75 1.01 2.56 2.61 1.96-0.04 1.48 1.47 0.65-0.22 3.56-1.63 1.81 0.74 1.45 1.14 0.07 4.6-2.65 3.12-0.7 2.12 2.23 2.3-0.98 6.86-0.23-1.58 5.12-1.57 1.55 1.82 1.13 0.46 4.61 4.18 1.5 0.85-0.3 0.69 0.65-0.18 1.23 3.23-0.23 2.25 1.4 0.93-1.02-2.04 3.05-1.08 4.1 2.2 4.93-1.9 3.28-0.47 3.37-2.58-1.3-0.32-1.05-5.82 2.53-0.11 3.47 1.61 3-0.84 0.45 0.27 0.77-2.69 3.02-0.76 0.2-2.96-1.87-1.56 1.82-0.13 1.5 2.03 0.6 1.88 2.37 4.4 2.7-1.57 2.92 0.68 1.62-6.28 0.42-1.36-1.92-1.69-0.4-7.05 2.95-0.44-1.1-1.36 0.15-0.7 0.85-1.93-1.4-0.58-3.09-3.77 1.94-1.66 1.72-0.96-2.49-2.09 1.35-3.67 0.77-2.58-3.64-1.38 0.57-1.34-3.54-1.59 0.27-4.08 5.29h-1.8l-1.33-0.92-0.84 1.05-2.66 1.14-2.36-0.64 2.9-6.07-1.44-3.47 1.04-2.47-0.9-1.42-2.12-0.18-0.25-1-3.48-0.92-0.13-1.15-1.01-0.58 0.3-1.32-1.74-3.37 0.2-4.53 1.14-0.97-0.6-0.75 0.41-0.55 3.58-1.9h1.33l0.57-1.68 1.94-2.05 0.84-3.61 1.2-0.25 1.65 0.95 0.82-0.42 0.95-4.16 1.9-2.4 0.89-2.8 1.72-0.86-0.99-2.43-1.11-0.2-2.47 1.41-1.08-0.58-0.14-1.28 7.17-8.9 0.01-3.03 1.56-3.34-2.87-2.68 2.12-4.29 0.37-2.87 2.78 1.01 1.35-0.71-0.53-2.83 1.32-1.76-1.47-2.97 2.13-1.2 2.33 0.93 1.25-1.36 0.22-1.43-0.65-0.96-3.13-0.75 0.03-1.89 2.25-2.76 2.64-0.53 0.73-2.29 1.55-1.08-2.95-2.29 0.21-0.88-2.06-2.82-1.6 2.19-1.53-0.86-4.27 2.72-0.38-0.93 0.63-1.81-1.25-0.53-0.17-0.75 1.17-0.99-0.78-0.17 0.4-1.36-1.47-1.51-3.36-1.21-0.77 0.88-3.47 0.18-1.23 0.95-3.18-1.1-1.95 0.57-0.82-0.75-2.12 0.12-1-1.61-0.03-1.58-13.9-5.87 4.62-1.41-0.03 0.55 4.02-2.02 0.97-10.51 7.04-10.02 32.14-10.03 9.29-7.96-9.59-16.35-1.86-10.57-1.21-3.09-2.33-16.06 8.4 1.65 2.66 2.11 5.21-0.54 10.41-3.85 3.89 3.98 0.92-0.89 1.63-0.15-1.14-2.18-0.02-4.27-2.13-3.61-0.63-5.82-3.98-3.89-3.94-2.64-0.25-1.27 1.23-3.59-3.3-1.04 1.18-2.8-1.44-7.46-2.89-1.53-4.38-0.59-2.65-1.07-1.1-1.4-1.07-5.66z" title="Limburg" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-NB" d="m316.7 643.94 3.01 3.8 4.24 1.94 3.23 4.64 1.69 0.08 1.54-1.63 1.88-0.25 2.39 2.07 3.61 1.76-0.43 3.11 1.03 1.3-2.53 2.57 0.06 1.86 5.59-1.43 5.19 0.69 3.72-0.82 4.84 2.5 3.35-1.73 4.62 0.87 8.97-5.07 1.74-7.68 5.9-8.91 1.3-0.03 1.96 2.4 1.58 0.66 3.23 0.05 2.85-1.1 1.49-3.52 1.54-0.66 1.57 0.51 2.44 2.43 3.29 0.82 1.01-0.31 1.88-2.55 4.72-0.59 5.57 2.58 2.79 0.18 3.07 5.54 1.69 1.07 2.96 0.51 3.08 3.83 3.75 0.92 2.28 3.44 2.23 1.43 3.4 0.26 10.97-1.79 2.37 0.43 2.03 1.91 1.06 5.66 1.11 1.4 2.64 1.07 4.38 0.59 2.9 1.53 1.44 7.46-1.19 2.8 3.31 1.04-1.23 3.59 0.25 1.27 3.94 2.64 3.97 3.89 0.63 5.82 2.14 3.61 0.02 4.27 1.14 2.18-1.63 0.15-0.92 0.89-3.89-3.99-10.41 3.86-5.21 0.53-2.66-2.11-8.4-1.65 2.33 16.06 1.22 3.09 1.85 10.57 9.59 16.35-9.29 7.96-32.14 10.03-7.04 10.02-0.96 10.52-4.02 2.02 0.03-0.55-4.62 1.41-0.6-0.53-0.71-4.92 0.14-5.77-4.62-4.31-1.76-3.08-4.05-1.14-0.95-0.08-2.86 3.79-3.85 0.73-0.49 1.49-0.89 0.1-2.6 3.46-11.31-3.03-1.57 3.08-6.73 0.35-4.78-1.21-4.41 1.01-1.44-1.39 2.14-9.51-6.19-4.01-4.13 1.36-1.77 1.39-4.46-1.36-0.41-8.26-9.53-11.53 5.16-9.84-4.15-9.83-5.22-0.33-1.12-1.93 0.08-1.67-0.71-0.3-3.99 3.85-0.9 6.89-6.22 5.27-5.55 6.98-0.54-0.83 0.3 0.99-1.01 0.46-1.14-0.33 1.6-0.43-2.14-1.47-1.57-2.83-0.93 0.56-1.28-0.86 0.19-0.61-0.6 0.48-1.38-0.35-1.41 1.95-2.52-1.49-0.81 0.68-1.17-0.53-7.47 1.49-2.77-1.52-0.68-3.34 0.93-0.94 1.72-0.15 0.41 0.81 6.3 2.03 1.23 1.11 1.28-0.03-0.51-0.56 1-0.86h-2.71l-1.03-5.97 1.68-2.91 0.84 0.66 0.87-0.79-1.57-1.19 0.85-4.51-3.15-0.76-0.85-2.86-6.92-2.31-3.17 1.19-1.12 2.53-2.55 1.34-2.18 3.85-1.93 0.46-1.63 3.85-4.1 1.87 0.38 4.43-1.63 0.53-1.17-0.43-1.9 0.99-1.74-0.89-8.42-1.57-6.31 2.35-0.85-6.58 2.72-5.95-1.68-2.46-10.1 1.19-1.58 1.65-3.42 0.61-9.27 4.91-0.73 0.91 2.26 0.28 1 2.68-0.92 0.56 0.35 1.21-1.76 1.7 1.35 3.31 6.2 8.17-0.87 1.04 0.82 1.72-1.44-0.28-4.37 2.2-2.71 0.25-5.55-0.76-1.22-4.75-9.19 0.28-0.54-1.59-1-0.13-0.52-1.14 0.66-2.28-0.81-4.96 1.9-2.4-8.85-19.84-0.03-1.95 2.67-8.07 0.09-2.54-1.41-2.79-5.22-6.4-0.74-2.59 1.34-4.75 1.8-1.78 4.35-1.91 1.68-3.15 4.29 0.51 9.08-2.52 3.29-1.53 2.79-2.26 1.46-3.44 2.44-2.98 0.89-0.03 0.44-1.15 3.21-2.7 11.88 3.97 3.48 0.36 11.87-3.26 2.5-2.01 9.97-2.85 4.79-3.39 5.51-5.33 2.25-5.74 2.45-2.91 4.57-1.99 7.91 0.1 3.39-2.14 2.86-2.96 3.73-1.86 4.38-0.41 10.01 1.82zm-10.54 94.93-1.35 1.97-0.14-1.65-0.51 0.43v-0.94l-0.87 0.53 0.59 0.71-0.27 1.54-0.9 0.46 3.59 1.57 0.55-0.78-0.38-0.63 0.98-0.68-1.42-0.38-0.19-0.81 0.97 0.1-0.62-1.11 1.5-0.76 0.22 0.53 0.98-1.16-0.35-0.58-0.74 0.73-2.93 0.05 1.29 0.86zm2.5 0.81-0.71-0.58-0.41 0.43 1.12 0.15zm-9.09 4.83-0.4 0.53 0.43-0.1-0.03-0.43zm6.73 3.7-1.6 0.46 0.59 0.58-0.66 0.56 1.84-0.3-0.17-1.3z" title="Noord-Brabant" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-NH" d="m364.17 419.06 8.62 3.83 7.09 7.5-0.36 0.26-7.01-7.42-8.23-3.59h-2.78l2.67-0.58zm-94.39-72.61-8.24 1.02-1.69 0.92 0.81 0.81-0.55 0.55-1.39-0.1-0.87-1.34 0.9-1.68 4.13-2.44 3.37 0.47 3.42 1.23 0.11 0.56zm55.41 8.52-2.14 1.73-0.38 2.49 1.47-0.26 10.35 20.25-1.52 18.28 1.22 0.08 0.67 1.17 0.87 3.63 4.43 4.51 1.17 0.39 1.77 0.03 1.41-0.94 2.52-3.7 4.46 0.26 3.39 1.77 3.54-0.7 0.43 0.5-1.55 0.55 2.15-0.13 1.85 1.23 0.68 7.14 3.1 1.9-1.2-0.1-0.22 1.38-2.94 1.67 0.51 1.3-5.79 1.48-1.65 7.31-0.79 1.17-3.69 2.06-1.5 2.16-3.92 1.01-2.33 2.47-5.05 0.88-1.17-3.33-2.15 0.16-2.63-2.78-2.2 0.65-1.17 1.2-0.21-0.68-1.36 0.21 0.11 0.96-1.08-1.95-0.93 0.03-1.16 1.25-2.75 1.25-0.44 1.01 0.81 7.2-0.43 1.01 1.93 5.38-0.25 1.66 1.91 1.79 1.91 4.26-0.11 1.53 2.5 5.16 0.7 0.03-0.17 1.01 1.08 0.88 0.66 2.2-2.34 3.53-1.11-0.08-0.47 0.62 0.08 2.72 1.16 1.35-0.1 1.11-2.72-0.13-1.91 0.96-0.7-0.41 1.31 2.07 0.79-1.06 1.08 0.26-0.81 1.66 0.02 3.68 4.78 0.91 1.65-0.41 0.3-3.26 1.46-1.92-1.27-7.72 1.82 5.26 1.36 1.66 3.75 0.28-3.75 1.61-1.09 1.14h-1.17l-0.47 3.21-1.07 1.66-0.7 0.34-0.08-0.91-1.15 1.04-1.5 4.35-2.07-0.1-1.22 1.79-2.2 1.47-1.22 3.41-2.14 1.14 0.43 0.67-0.63 1.86-1.82-1.27-2.83 1.19-2.64-2.38-0.71 0.83 0.47 1.24 2.55 1.32-1.22 1.4-0.47-1.06-0.85 0.72 3.29 2.12 2.42 2.92 2.34 0.47 2.18-1.03 1.12 1.09-0.98 1.37 0.44 0.96 0.74-0.08-0.16-0.7 1.42 0.54 4.02-0.21 1.28-0.93 2.28 0.34 2.99 2.25 4.15 1.06 2.23 2.07 11-1.88 9.73 2.45 4.65 3.07 3.81 3.77-4.73 3.38-4.62-0.83-1.5 1.37-0.93-0.41-2.53 5.21-3.47 3.09-0.49 7.94-4.37 8.73-10.82-0.59-0.28-1.13 2.93-1.96 0.84-1.49-1.99-3.97-1.9-1.06-0.49 0.95-6.79 0.18-5.24-2.14-0.63-2.19 3.31-1.49-2.18-2.14-0.57-2.86-1.36 0.57-1.5-4.69 4.05-1.21 0.17-1.14 1.28-0.67 1.2 0.93-0.76-1.99-1.68 0.13-1.23 1.47-1.5-1.26-0.71 0.21-2.14 2.68h-0.7l-1.36-3.2-0.98-0.41-2.45 0.18-2.63 2.63-4.45-0.93-1.2 0.52 0.21 2.24-2.33 1.7-1.17 2.24-6.77 0.13-5.54 5.26-2.98 1.37h-2.47l-1.65-0.36-1.55 0.67-0.92 1.34-4.76 2.65-1.23 1.55-0.92-0.7-0.24-5.59-3.09-0.49-2.66 1.83-3.61 0.28-5.13 2.99-3.24 0.23-4.6-1.21-1.68 0.57-2.33-0.54-1.08-0.88-0.16-1.31 1.39-2.11 1.25-6.55-0.29-2.04 3.13-3.17 3.81-8.44-4.3-1.63-2.14 0.59-1 1.86-10.74-4.85 10.57-27.46 0.85-6.03 0.81-1.11-0.6-1.71 3.07-7.78 4.05-22.58 4.65-39.09 1.42-6.7 2.28-5.04 2.67-9.06 3.67-14.66 0.82-3.79 0.7-14.14 1.68-4.48 1.42-1.31 6.98-0.63-0.13 0.58 1-0.05-0.79 0.66 1.19 1.83 1.16-0.31 0.55-1.28-0.97-0.86 1.54-0.31 0.4 2.04-1.98 5.48 2.6 5.55 10.79 6.54 5.14-1.36 4.97-2.51 2.42-3.06 0.68-2.33 1.5-1.34 5.43-1.57 1.84 0.52 2.47-0.81 1.33 0.94 19.91-17.64 0.65 0.87-17.8 15.49zm-27.61-57.19 1.28 0.26 3.04 5.21-0.81 1.68-0.32-0.87-0.13 12.46-0.62 1.89-3.85 3.39-0.14 2.71-1.69 3.05-1.68 0.87-1.28 1.89-3.88 0.94-4.26 5.54 0.71 0.89-0.46 0.66-6.46-2.05-0.41 0.34 0.6 1 1.84 0.73 1.44 1.55-1.52-0.47-1.71 1 0.43 0.58-2.9 0.31-1.61 1.1-2.69-4.01-0.55-2.86 0.25-4.88 1.82-7.9 4.53-9.35 11.52-18.15 4.07-4.32 1.46-0.54999 1 0.41999 2.48 3.92 0.5 3.02z" title="Noord-Holland" class="land"/>
            <path id="NL-OV" d="m493.68 377 2.35 3.63 10.77 12.33-5.16 5.71-0.19 1.26-6.71 2.42-1.06 1.49 5.8 14.96 3 3.57 1.22-0.5 2.41 0.68 0.85-1.17 2.11-0.5 1.59 1.49 2.69 0.72 1.77 2.11 1.13 0.08 1.34 1.25 1.71-0.88 1.43 1.58 1.1-0.91 4.12-1.06 0.54 0.93-0.38 1.69 5.84 4.22 1.78 3.82 0.4 2.71 1.34 1.56 1.82-1.43 1.51 0.05 0.5-0.91 1.43 0.73 1.96-2.47 0.55 2.02 1.48 1.28 2.67-0.37 1.12-2.47 1.51 1.69 4.49 0.32 2.22 2.08-0.94-9.78 6.03-4.63 10.1-2.27 15.03 6.46-1.52 5.74 1.82 0.11 2.2 2.94-1.08 6.96 7.5 6.62-3.07 0.86-3.48-0.78-1.67 3.72-5.51-1.12 3.94 8.23-1.12 8.94 9.95 6.45 2.61 0.78 12.1-0.02-0.01 2.43 1.63-0.34 12.36 4.02 3.3-2.57 2.33-4.92 1.76-1.24 2.18 4.79 1.3 5.41 1.77 1.61 2.23 5.64 3.63 0.41 2.37 6.75-0.11 5.51-2.66 3.72-1.41 3.43-0.27 2.53-3.04 6.38 0.24 4.23 2.53 4.69 3.17 3.54-0.7 1.62-3.43 2.22-3.12 0.56-2.39-0.95-2.88 0.7-0.88 1.21-0.62 3.58-3.88 6.62-6.87 1.33-0.45 1.7-3.55 3.3-1.5 6.71-2.66 2.57-15.02 0.59-7.13 0.05-8.49-2.98 1.68-2.7-0.41-4.01 0.54-1.37-0.73-1.26-3.26-1.72-0.66-0.05-0.78 1.36-1.61-1.34-2.65 2.37-1.33-1.23 0.4-1.47-2.52-2.22-5.8 1.42-6.29-1.03-3.56 0.9-2.58-1.95-0.94-3.38-2.3-0.72-1.3-2.63-3.19-3.34-1.76-3.43 0.05-1.29-5.52-0.62-4.75 0.93-2 1.49-0.09 2.19-2.66 0.42-3.27-0.03-1.21-1.39-2.2 1-1.04-0.36-0.08 0.75-3.62-0.26-5.05-1.05-2.31-1.73-4.13-0.03-0.59 2.53-0.72-0.77-0.16 1.16-0.62-0.26 0.87 1.52-0.32 0.77-0.72-1.88-2.42-1.11-0.43-1.65 1.44-1.57 0.19-1.42-1.96 0.18-2.69-1.05 0.91-2.32-2.84-4.6-0.13-2.5-1.27-2.6-0.33-0.6-2.71-0.36-0.63-4-1.57-0.21 0.91-3.12 0.01-5.14 2.87-1.89-2.34-1.55-0.26-1.53 0.63-0.87 3.14-0.6 3.31-1.58 1.97-7.96-0.99-3.55-4.21-5.2-0.46-6.53-1.35-1.63-3.65-2.1-1.82-3.68-4.64-3.01-1.11 1.32-1.71 0.6-6.89 7.13-1.37-1.97-2.94 1.73-0.62-0.57-1.2 0.55-2.15-5.11-3.21-4.51-2.46-2.18-2.15 0.8-1.74-8.61-6.74-7.2-5.19-0.2 0.06-6.86 9.39 0.02 1.25-1.04 9.32-2.05 2.06 1.35 2.34-0.29 3.87-2.62 5.24-1.15 3.56-2.36 0.79-1.36-2.28-2.52-2.57-0.7-2.52-2.21-5.81-1.59-0.06-0.89 1.79-2.03 2.88-2.16 0.38-1.59-2.06-3.75-1.11-0.57-3.29-9.31-10.22-8.35-3.59-1.25h-2.9l-3.58-4.88 3.79-2.64 2.16 1.49 0.35 1.07 1-0.57 5.87 1.56 3.31-1.56 4.21-3.97-0.02-2.04 0.71-0.86 2.41-0.52 1.47 0.6 0.02-1.39 2.83-0.94 2.15 5.38 2.09 1 4.13-1.13 0.71 1.44 3.73-2.01-0.2-3.19 1.79-0.73 2.77 0.1z" title="Overijssel" class="land"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: With the help of data visualization software

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an hyperlink?
If this is the case, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/447dpk2o/12/

The hyperlink is declared like this:

```
<a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <circle cx="450" cy="300" r="20" fill="rgba(255,0,0,.5)"/>
</a>
```

And you need to add the following namespace in the root element:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```